# Where can I find some jokes in Korean online?

Tags: joke, resources

Is there any website that lists some Korean jokes?

It may be a funny short story or funny one liners or anything written entirely in Korean, and should be understandable to a native speaker.

I am **not** asking about the type of joke that derives its humour from a pun between English and Korean, which seems to be the only type of joke that Google shows in a search result.

Answer (score 3):

As a Korean who spends a lot of time on the internet, I would say there is no such website, unfortunately. At least, young people will not like the jokes in that kind of sites. Jokes were in such form in 15~ 20 years ago. 
But ever since pictures, clips, musics, drawings, and cartoons are all over on the internet, one-liner or pure text jokes never came back.

For funny stories, search for 컬투 사연 베스트. "cultwo show" is the most famous radio comedy show in Korea. They introduce listeners stories. And they DO know how to tell funny stories. You may find some of them with subtitles on Youtube.

In addition,
I recommend searching for 웃대 답베 = 웃긴 대학 답변 베스트 = Humor university(name of a community)'s best replies. Usually captured and spread over the internet. Most people find it funny but small number of people may find it too aggressive or dirty. You will need to read main article and also all the replies to get the best reply's point. It is not to get the idea at first. Actually most of old Koreans will fail to understand the jokes. But, these are best combinations of all the current issues, interests, gossips, seasoned with tons of sarcasm (and dirty jokes some... many.. times)

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly hard to find online websites filled with one-liners in Korean. But at least, I found one. Hopefully this will be satisfying: http://tip.daum.net/question/39297242

Comment: Oh, please just read and DO NOT use jokes in the link.. They'll keep a straight face and ask back "How old are you?" or "You seem like a old man".

Comment: @JinyoungKim Mission Accomplished. XD